# "The requested URL was not found on this server." When runnnig a Contao website on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS?

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I've received a website that uses the Contao 3.4.50 CMS with my mission being slowly upgrading it to the newest version but first I need to get the entire website working on my localhost.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- Apache
- Php 5.6
- MySQL version 5.7.42

I've gotten to the point where the homepage of the website is correctly displayed on localhost in Firefox. The problem occurs when I try to switch to another page. As soon as the page changes I get the following:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

I've checked my `localconfig.php` file and the credentials for connecting to my local database are correct. If I change any of them even the home page stops showing making me believe I am successfully connecting to my database.

I've also checked that my `.htaccess` file is in the root folder of my Contao website, and it is.

Here is an example of a line in my Apache error log:

```
"GET /izobrazevanje/izobrazevalni-dogodki.html HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "http://localhost/"
```

When I check my MySQL database I can see that in the tl_page table I do have a row which has `izobrazevanje/izobrazevalni-dogodki` set as its alias.

Also my `website-archive.conf` in my `/etc/apache/sites-available/` directory looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName website-archive
    ServerAlias www.website-archive
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website-archive/sic-22-06-2023/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas why the other pages are not displaying?

Answer (score 3):

There are few things that may be responsible for this problem.

#### `mod_rewrite` is disabled

You may have to enable `mod_rewrite` on your server by executing these commands:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Missing or wrong `AllowOverride` directive

Check your vhost config for missing the [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive. The default vhost config file is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` but this may differ depending on your settings. Make sure you have `AllowOverride All` for the directory where your Contao CMS is installed. It should looks something like this:

```xml
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

#### Errors in your `.htaccess` file

This is the less probable scenario, if you are using the default `.htaccess`. However, if you have made some changes to it, make sure they are correct.

Comment: I do have it enabled, I tried it again just in case but the issue was not fixed @sotirov

Comment: @Mesarich I have updated my answer.

Comment: I've added what you recommended to my website-archive.conf (as that was the one where i changed the root document in order to get the website to appear). Of course i changed the /var/www/html to my directory (that being /var/www/website-archive/sic-22-06-2023/) and now the error is gone but a blank white page appears instead of the expected result @sotirov

Comment: @Mesarich This sounds like something else. Check the Apache's error logs.

Comment: thank you for all the help, i wrote the answer for the things i had to further do in order to get things to work, please let me know if any of my answer formatting is incorrect or needs improvement

Answer (score 1):

After following [@soritov suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1497532/1157209) and adding the

```
<Directory /var/www/website-archive/sic-22-06.2023/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To my `website-archive.conf` file and checking my apache error logs I needed to install two modules and add two lines to my php.ini file using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml php5.6-mbstring
```

For installing the modules and

`sudo nano /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`

To access my `php.ini` file in which I added the following lines under:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
extension=dom.so
extension=mbstring.so
```